# how broken image file when ios multipart to server

Tags: ios, image, post, multipart

my code

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlHeader, urlBody];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"--Kqcekgk5QEa0NR71B";
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSMutableData *imageBody = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@", BOARD_ID, boardType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%d", BOARD_SEQ, [boardSeq intValue]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


for(int i=0; i<[imagesArr count]; i++) {
    if([[imagesArr objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imagesArr objectAtIndex:i] , 90);

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"FILE_UPLOAD%d\"; filename=\"IMG_IPHONE%d.jpg\"\r\n\r\n", i+1, i+1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
[body appendData:imageBody];
```

send to server success but image file type as text/plan
i use image .png

why image file broken ?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove \r\n at the beginning like this

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```